# How can i make a requestAnimationFrame method modular?

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

I wrote a simple function like below to animate the canvas background when mousemovement occurs close to edges and sides

World.js file:

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    x = window.scrollX+e.clientX - (window.scrollX + canvas_planets.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    y = window.scrollY+e.clientY - (window.scrollY + canvas_planets.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    if(movementStatus){
        pixels=3;
        moveCanvas();
    }
}
function moveCanvas() {
    movementStatus=false;
    // left top corner
    if(x <= 50 && y <= 50){
        if (canvasPoint_X > 0 && canvasPoint_Y > 0){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X-pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //left side
    if(x <= 50 && y > 50 && y < 450){
        if (canvasPoint_X > 0){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X= canvasPoint_X-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //left bottom corner
    if(x <= 50 && y >= 450){
        if (canvasPoint_X > 0 && canvasPoint_Y < (imageHeight-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X-pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //top side
    if(x > 50 && x <= 450 && y <= 50){
        if (canvasPoint_Y > 0){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //bottom side
    if(x > 50 && x <= 450 && y >= 450){
        if (canvasPoint_Y < (imageHeight-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //right top corner
    if(x > 450 && y <= 50){
        if (canvasPoint_Y > 0 && canvasPoint_X < (imageWidth-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X+pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //right side
    if(x > 450 && y > 50 && y < 450){
        if (canvasPoint_X < (imageWidth-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //right bottom corner
    if(x > 450 && y >= 450){
        if (canvasPoint_Y < imageHeight-500 && canvasPoint_X < (imageWidth-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X+pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (x > 495 || x < 5 || y >495 || y < 5){
        movementStatus =true;
        return;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(moveCanvas);
}
```

After this to make my script more readable i decided to put movecanvas method in a seperate js file named Mycanvas.js and then edited the code according to that like below:

World.js file:

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    x = window.scrollX+e.clientX - (window.scrollX + canvas_planets.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    y = window.scrollY+e.clientY - (window.scrollY + canvas_planets.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    if(movementStatus){
        pixels=3;
        [movementStatus, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y] = myCanvas.moveCanvas(x,y,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y,ctx_stars,pixels,StarsImg,imageHeight,imageWidth);
    }
}
```

Mycanvas.js file:

```
export let movementStatus;
export const moveCanvas = (x,y,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y,ctx_stars,pixels,StarsImg,imageHeight,imageWidth) =>{
    movementStatus=false;
    if(x <= 50 && y <= 50){
        if (canvasPoint_X > 0 && canvasPoint_Y > 0){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X-pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if(x <= 50 && y > 50 && y < 450){
        if (canvasPoint_X > 0){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X= canvasPoint_X-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if(x <= 50 && y >= 450){
        if (canvasPoint_X > 0 && canvasPoint_Y < (imageHeight-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X-pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y+pixels;
            console.log("sol alt köşe")
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if(x > 50 && x <= 450 && y <= 50){
        if (canvasPoint_Y > 0){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if(x > 50 && x <= 450 && y >= 450){
        if (canvasPoint_Y < (imageHeight-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    //sağ üst köşe
    if(x > 450 && y <= 50){
        if (canvasPoint_Y > 0 && canvasPoint_X < (imageWidth-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X+pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y-pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if(x > 450 && y > 50 && y < 450){
        if (canvasPoint_X < (imageWidth-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if(x > 450 && y >= 450){
        if (canvasPoint_Y < imageHeight-500 && canvasPoint_X < (imageWidth-500)){
            ctx_stars.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx_stars.drawImage(StarsImg, canvasPoint_X, canvasPoint_Y, 500, 500, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            canvasPoint_X = canvasPoint_X+pixels;
            canvasPoint_Y = canvasPoint_Y+pixels;
        }else{
            movementStatus =true;
            return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
        }
    }
    if (x > 495 || x < 5 || y >495 || y < 5){
        movementStatus =true;
        return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(moveCanvas);
}
```

However after doing this, my working script stopped working and started to give me the fallowing error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the elements incorrectly, you need to return your elements as an array instead `return [movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y];` as `return movementStatus,canvasPoint_X,canvasPoint_Y;` would return only `canvasPoint_Y` causing the error

```js
function fn() {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}

[x, y, z] = fn();

console.log(x, y, z);
```

**Edit:**
Not all paths of the function `moveCanvas` return an array, for example the last line of the function, consider storing the return value first and check if it is an array:

Problem

```js
function fn() {
  if (false)
    return [1, 2, 3];
}

[x, y, z] = fn();

console.log(x, y, z);
```

Fix:

```js
function fn() {
  if (false)
    return [1, 2, 3];
}

k = fn();

if (k != undefined) {
  console.log(...k);
} else {
  console.log(k);
}
```

Comment: ok, it was my mistake to think when i return multiple elements it may automatically return them as an array, however it is still giving the same error